# Running Protractors in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor, jenkins-workflow, gulp-protractor, protractor-net

I was just wondering if it is possible to run protractor e2e tests in Jenkins with every build. Currently we trigger test cases manually and they are not part of Jenkins but somehow I need them to be run automatically and show the results (failures/pass) as part of the build.
Can anyone share their experience.

Regards
Syed Zaidy

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, you set this up under the **Build Triggers** section of your job.  You have the options to build periodically, build remotely, build after another project is built, or build after a push to GitHub/BitBucket.

You can also put your tests in the pipeline, "downstream" from another job, so they are automatically triggered whenever that job completes.

Comment: thanks Gunderson, I understand that but I was looking more on how to setup the environment. Jenkins is on a server with no browser.

Comment: Then you can setup a [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp), which has a Hub and Node(s).  Jenkins kicks off the test, sends them to the Hub, and the Hub routes them to the appropriate Nodes.  The machines that are running the tests on the browsers are your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run Protractor tests from a Jenkins job. To do this, you will need a headless browser. Read about Headless browsers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser):

You can follow the following instructions and install npm, protractor and chrome headless in the Jenkins box [here](https://gist.github.com/praphull27/6950d2a6c76a6e68acb7)